# Error in Eclipse: operator is undefined with EditText, double

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I am trying to make a simple tip calculator and have an EditText text field where you put in the amount of your total bill, then click on the percent button you want to calculate in tip (say, 10%) and then the onClickListener for that % button will calculate the tip and put the result into a different TextView field below itself.

However, I know I had to change my EditText for my total bill from a string to a double, and included code for that, but I still get the error when I try to multiply the total bill times the tip of 10%. Why?

**Here is my code:**

```
package com.example.nonitips;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText totalBill;
    public double billWithTip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        totalBill = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalBill);
    }

    public void onTen (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tipping at 10%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        totalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double bill = Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText().toString());
                bill = (totalBill * 0.10) + totalBill; //Error on this line.
            }
        });

    }

    public void onFifteen (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tipping at 15%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onTwenty (View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tipping at 20%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying edittext to double value? Is it make some sense?

Comment: The EditText value is going to be a double... it's just that in my xml file, it is set up as an EditText. Is there a way to set it up differently? I thought a conversion from text to double would work fine.

Comment: bill = (totalBill * 0.10) + totalBill; here totalBill denotes edit text.

Comment: @Lokesh, geez, thanks so much! that was really a simple error. Now it is not showing in my billWithTip field for some reason, but that is another question.

Comment: @Noni A: but where you are using billWithTip value.?

Comment: ithink u trying to calculate total bil so use "totalBill = (bill * 0.10) + bill;"

Comment: Hi Raj, the totalBill field is where the user inputs their numbers, and the onClick method is supposed to calculate the tip included... then after that, it is supposed to update a new field, called billWithTip. So I have to figure out how to get the newly figured out value into the billWithTip field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code of EditText click:

```
     totalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        double bill = Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText().toString());
                        billWithTip= (bill * 0.10) + billWithTip; 

     Toast.makeText(this, "Updated billWithTip"+billWithTip, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
billWithTip.setText(String.valueOf(billWithTip));
                    }
                });
```

Double to String convertion Example:

```
double total = 44; 
String total2 = String.valueOf(total);
```

Comment: Thanks Lokesh, that looked very good, but when I tried it, the billWithTip field did not update with the new bill value. :( The error is gone though, which is half the battle.

Comment: Where you want to display billWithTip value?? on totalBill Edittext??

Comment: No, it is on a new field, called billWithTip (that is the Id name). and billWithTip is already declared as a double.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that by saying billWithTip = (bill*0.10) + billWithTip; that the billWithTip would show a number now, but it does not show anything. Do you think I am missing something? It definitely received a number when the user input their total bill number (then went through the tip calculations)...

Comment: Thanks Lokesh, that is nice of you... only thing is this is an assignment and it must go into a TextView field, it can't be a Toast. and the TextView field already is named billWithTip (R.id), so not sure why it is not updating. Do you think I also have to convert the TextView into a double? The variable name itself (billWithTip) is already declared as a double in my main activity.

Comment: Check my answer now.. If billWithTip already defined TextView, then assign vlaue to it..

Comment: Darn, I get an error, says "cannot invoke text string on a double". Maybe I should change my billWithTip to a string instead? although the calculation answer will be a double...hmm.

Comment: No.. convert your double value to string while add it to textview

Comment: That sounds good, do you know the code for that? I am still learning :/

Comment: Thanks. sorry, i'm about to fall over from exhaustion from working on this for 10 hours and googling turns up lots of things to sift through, but I think this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiple EditText with double value. Use following code.

```
totalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double bill = Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText().toString());
                billWithTip= (bill * 0.10) + billWithTip; 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Jitesh, although this answer is a repeat of one above... but may I ask, what is a multiple EditText? I think I created my EditText widget just from a simple Plain Text I dragged over. Is that okay?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake it is multiply.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        try this one..
        totalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     //   double bill = Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText().toString());
                      //  bill = (totalBill * 0.10) + totalBill; //Error on this line.



    try {
    String bills= totalBill.getText().toString();
  Double protein = Double.parseDouble(bills); // Make use of autoboxing.It's also easier to read.
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // p did not contain a valid double
    }

        if(protein == null || protein.isEmpty()) {

          bill = 0.0;

        } else {

          bills= Double.parseDouble(noKids.getText().toString());
        Double protein = Double.parseDouble(bills);
          bill = (protein * 0.10) + protein ;
        }
                    }
                });

    thank you..
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
totalBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double bill = Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText().toString());
            bill = (bill  * 0.10) + bill ); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Nand, I guess you and Lokesh did post at the same time. :)